# How can I explain a part of my predictions as a whole with SHAP values? (and not every single prediction)

Tags: python, shap

**Background information**

I fit a classifier on my training data. When testing my fitted best estimator, I predict the probabilities for one of the classes. I order both my X_test and my y_test by the probabilites in a descending order.

**Question**

I want to understand which features were important (and to what extend) for the classifier to predict only the 500 predictions with the highest probability as a whole, not for each prediction. Is the following code correct for this purpose?

```
y_test_probas = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

explainer = shap.Explainer(clf, X_train)  # <-- here I put the X which the classifier was trained on?

top_n_indices = np.argsort(y_test_probas)[-500:]

shap_values = explainer(X_test.iloc[top_n_indices])  # <-- here I put the X I want the SHAP values for?

shap.plots.bar(shap_values)
```

Unfortunately, the [shap documentation (bar plot)](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/bar.html) does not cover this case. Two things are different there:

1. They use the data the classifier was trained on <--> I want to use the data the classifier is tested on
2. They use the whole X and not part of it <--> I want to use only part of the data

**Minimal reproducible example**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shap
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# Load the Titanic Survival dataset
data = pd.read_csv("https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1166/stuff/titanic.csv")

# Preprocess the data
data = data.drop(["Name"], axis=1)
data = data.dropna()
data["Sex"] = (data["Sex"] == "male").astype(int)

# Split the data into predictors (X) and response variable (y)
X = data.drop("Survived", axis=1)
y = data["Survived"]

# Split the dataset into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Fit a logistic regression classifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)

# Get the predicted class probabilities for the positive class
y_test_probas = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

# Select the indices of the top 500 test samples with the highest predicted probability of the positive class
top_n_indices = np.argsort(y_test_probas)[-500:]

# Initialize the Explainer object with the classifier and the training set
explainer = shap.Explainer(clf, X_train)

# Compute the SHAP values for the top 500 test samples
shap_values = explainer(X_test.iloc[top_n_indices, :])

# Plot the bar plot of the computed SHAP values
shap.plots.bar(shap_values)
```

I don't want to know how the classifier decides **all** the predictions, but on the **predictions with the highest probability**. Is that code suitable to answer this question? If not, how would a suitable code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Your code is correct, with one potential point to discuss (see below).

### How are the SHAP values calculated?

Your model is linear, so `shap.Explainer()` uses a linear explainer in its simplest form. This means: The SHAP value of feature j of an observation is simply

coef_j * (value - mean_j),

where

- coef_j: jth regression coefficient
- value: Value of feature j of first row
- mean_j: Average of feature j in 100 randomly sampled observations of the dataset passed to `shap.Explainer()`

The big mistery: Calculating means is much cheaper than subsampling, thus why is the linear explainer doing subsampling in this case? Oh well...

### Example

We can verify above calculations by using only the first 100 rows of the training data, so that no subsampling is done:

```
top_1 = top_n_indices[0]
explainer = shap.Explainer(clf, X_train[0:100])
explainer(X_test.iloc[[top_1]])
```

This results in

```
.values =
array([[-0.71299643, -0.90613007,  0.53047584, -1.87629253, -0.21875983,
         0.04461552]])

.base_values =
array([-0.7436993])

.data =
array([[ 3. ,  1. , 14. ,  5. ,  2. , 46.9]])
```

We can easily reconstruct this by manually calculating:

```
(X_test.iloc[[top_1]] - X_train[0:100].mean()) * clf.coef_
```

with output:

```
Pclass       Sex        Age         Sib/Spo     Par/Child   Fare
-0.712996   -0.90613    0.530476    -1.876293   -0.21876    0.044616
```

### Point to discuss

Your explainer uses 100 randomly sampled rows from the training data to calculate the means. These are probably very non-representative for the data you would like to explain, thus it might be more correct to pass as background data to `shap.Explainer()` rather the data of interest `X_test.iloc[top_n_indices, :]`.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your response. I am really sorry for using `LogisticRegression` in my example since I didn't expect it would make such a difference for the answer. In fact, I am using a non-linear model, namely `imblearn`'s `BalancedRandomForestClassifier`. So linearity of the model isn't a concern anymore?
Second, unfortunately I cannot follow your argument of "100 randomly sampled rows". Where does that come from? Are you referring to my rows with the highest probability for class 1?

Comment: No problem@DataJanitor: The 100 random sample happens hidden in the Python code of the chosen explainer. I don't know what SHAP algorithm is being applied to imblearn's `BalancedRandom`. Definitively not a linear SHAP decomposition ;)